# TypeError list indices must be integers or slices not str

Tags: python, typeerror

I am new in python and I have the following problem. When I run this code:

```
import numpy as np

my_file1 = open("ex2-dnalist1.txt")
my_file2 = open("ex2-dnalist2.txt")

lines1 = my_file1.readlines()
lines2 = my_file2.readlines()

def EditDistanceM(s,t):
    size_x = len(s) + 1    
    size_y = len(t) + 1 
    matrix = np.zeros((size_x, size_y)) 
    for x in range(size_x):
        matrix[x,0] = x
    for y in range(size_y):
        matrix[0,y] = y
    for x in range(1, size_x):
        for y in range(1, size_y):
            if s[x-1] == t[y-1]:        
                matrix[x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1, 
                    matrix[x-1, y-1],   
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1  
                    )
            else:                      
                matrix[x,y] = min(
                    matrix[x-1, y] + 1,
                    matrix[x-1, y-1] +1,
                    matrix[x, y-1] + 1
                    )
                
    print(matrix)
    return (matrix[size_x - 1, size_y - 1])

list_10 = []
for n in lines1[n]:
    for m in lines2[m]:
        EditDistanceM(lines1[n],lines2[m])
        list_10 += EditDistanceM(lines1[n],lines2[m])
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-957aaf99b22e> in <module>
     34 
     35 list_10 = []
---> 36 for n in lines1[n]:
     37     for m in lines2[m]:
     38         EditDistanceM(lines1[n],lines2[m])

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I get the same error even if I write n=0 and m=0 outside the for loop, but this time for the EditDistancM function inside the two for loops. Can you please help me?

Comment: `for n in lines1[n]` doesn't make sense... It seems that you might need to spend a little more time with some Python tutorials and beginners books, to learn how `for` loops really work.

Comment: the loop `for n in ...` will change value of n. If inside your lines there are characters, they will be the new value of n. Then loop executes again and code `lines1[n]` now indexes using string value of `n`.

Answer (score 2):

your mistake is here:

```py
list_10 = []
for n in lines1[n]:
    for m in lines2[m]:
        EditDistanceM(lines1[n],lines2[m])
        list_10 += EditDistanceM(lines1[n],lines2[m])
```

when you want to loop over `list`, you don't need to use like `lines1[n]`.
when you use `lines1[n]` it's mean you want to access `list/array` element.
when you want to loop over a `list/array` you need to use only `list/array` variable.
also when you want to add `element/item` to your `list/array` you need to use `.append` method, not `+=`.

try this:

```py
list_10 = []
for n in lines1:
    for m in lines2:
        EditDistanceM(n,m)
        list_10.append(EditDistanceM(n,m))
```

Comment: But `n` and `m` aren't indexes into the `lines1` and `lines2` lists, making the "fixed" code also wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right, I forgot that, my answer edited.